# Use Sony PSP to control and visualize a robot running ROS?

Tags: control, ros, ros-melodic, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the launch of Steam Deck ($399), I saw some roboticists thinking about using them to control, visualize sensor data, maps, and other cool stuff. I was wondering if maybe a Sony PSP could do the same job, but with a lower price point, around $150.

Has anyone tried that yet or something similar?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392176/use-sony-psp-to-control-and-visualize-a-robot-running-ros?/) by [RodrigoCatto](https://answers.ros.org/users/63903/rodrigocatto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2021-12-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-03**:
This is interesting and great low cost solution. Do you have a link for examples of using Steam Deck for robotics application, couldn't find it. Sorry it's not answer to your question, but definitely cool idea.

**Comment by [RodrigoCatto](https://answers.ros.org/users/63903/rodrigocatto/) on 2021-12-03**:
I don't have any examples from steam deck (I think the delivery got delayed). My inspiration came from Boston Dynamics Spot Mini controller and Clear Path Teleoperation Package device. It would be nice to control the robot using the joystick while watching the map being created on the screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen someone use a [Nintendo Switch](https://www.reddit.com/r/ROS/comments/lbv4qk/ros_controller_using_nintendo_switch/).

---

Originally posted by [kscottz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13336/kscottz/) with karma: 209 on 2021-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-03**:
I feel bad for my kids but I’ll start hacking their toys